# Using Go on the command line, how do I hide command line input from the user's terminal?

Tags: go, terminal

I'm writing a simple command line utility that requests a password from the user.  I settled on using bufio for reading user input and can't figure out how to hide the password on the user's terminal.  Is this functionality in Go's standard library, or do I need to use OS-level functionality to accomplish this?  (This is probably only going to run on Linux, but would prefer something that works on Windows also.)

Comment: I have not used it myself, so I won't post as an answer, but this might be what you want: http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/gopass

Answer (score 3):

What you want is turning off echoing. This is usually achieved by configuring the terminal driver, *termios*. Your best bet is to read Linux' documentation of that driver ([termios(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/termios)). As far as I am concerned, you need to turn off `ECHO` before reading a password. After reading the password, turn on `ECHO` again. Do not use *bufio* as you do not want to have buffering interfere with low-level terminal stuff. You can access the requires system calls from the [syscall](http://golang.org/pkg/syscall) package.

*termios* is available on every UNIX-like platform. This includes Linux, BSD, OS X, and Solaris but not Microsoft Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [termbox](http://github.com/nsf/termbox-go) that uses keyboard input without output. So far i can tell, this works on Windows, but i am unsure if this works on Linux (i guess it does).
Once installed, there is a _demos folder, inside of this folder there is an example called keyboard.go. Once started, it will show a keyboard and it highlights the keys that are pressed. However, it does work on my pc, but when i press space bar/enter/function keys or CTRL-(any)key, the program hangs. Maybe it's a bug in the code or inside of Termbox. I have not figured out yet. Also, you need to use CGO to use termbox to run.

Screenshot:

[image]